# Convert Jackson object into JSONObject java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a Jackson object into a JSONObject?

What I've tried, however I don't believe this is the correct approach.

```
public JSONObject toJSON() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();       
    return new JSONObject(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Warnings(warnings)));
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The way you are doing is work fine, because i also use that way to make a JSONobject.

here is my code

```
 public JSONObject getRequestJson(AccountInquiryRequestVO accountInquiryRequestVO) throws  JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
          ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          JSONObject jsonAccountInquiry;

           jsonAccountInquiry=new JSONObject(mapper.writeValueAsString(accountInquiryRequestVO));

  return jsonAccountInquiry;  
 }
```

its working fine for me. but you can always use JsonNode also
here is the sample code for that

```
JsonNode jsonNode=mapper.valueToTree(accountInquiryRequestVO);
```

its very easy to use.

Answer (score 9):

Right now, you are serializing your Pojo to a `String`, then parsing that `String` and converting it into a `HashMap` style object in the form of `JSONObject`.

This is very inefficient and doesn't accomplish anything of benefit.

Jackson already provides an [`ObjectNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html) class for interacting with your Pojo as a JSON object. So just convert your object to an `ObjectNode`. Here's a working example

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
        pojo.setAge(42);
        pojo.setName("Sotirios");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectNode node = mapper.valueToTree(pojo);
        System.out.println(node);
    }
}

class Pojo {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, the way you are doing it is fine.